# How to disable deleting collections and documents from firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

In Firebase's Firestore, a user **with write access to a project** can simply delete any document and even a whole collection with multiple documents with a single click. This is a major security problem as any of my team member may end up deleting a whole collection with millions of documents in under a minute, **through the Firebase console**.

Is there a way to disable this?

Deleting a whole collection with a click:

[image: user can delete a whole collection]

User can cherry pick and delete a document as well:

[image: user can delete a specific document]

Answer (score 2):

Collaborators to your project who have write permission to Firestore will be able to delete data, including collections. If you don't want a specific user to be able to delete collections, you should grant them view-only permission to the database in the project through the [<kbd>Users and permissions</kbd> panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/iam) in the Firebase console.

To delete a collection I nowadays have to type the name of that collection after clicking delete. This is to make it less likely that a collaborator who *should* be able to delete data, deletes an entire collection accidentally.

[image: Pop-up that is shown before deleting a collection]

Comment: Frank, I had the feeling the OP was asking for the possibility to grant write access **without** delete access. Currently, if I am not mistaking, through the User and Permissions panel it's kind of "all or nothing", i.e. if you can write you can also delete.

Comment: There is indeed no option to disable just delete.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, Frank.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think the feature can be useful if we can grant access to only a certain collection in Firestore. Because with the huge of data and diverse developer, the missing such feature is risky for the company. For instance, a junior developer who only develops a small feature have access to all of the collections in the database feels like non-sense. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: There is no way to distinguish between overwriting lots of data, or deleting it. I would recommend to only grant them access to places you trust them with. Aside from that, it never hurts to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: As of Aug 2021, I can - as a collaborator with 'Viewer' access - still delete documents and collections :( :( :(. It makes no sense

Comment: UPDATE: the observation above ^ is for a user who is a viewer in the Firebase console but an owner in the GCP (project) console. Looks like there's inconsistency between the two consoles

Comment: Thanks to @FrankvanPuffelen's suggestion - I just filed a feature request for this on Firebase https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/47757560-ability-to-disable-deleting-collections-and-docume 

Let us upvote it as much as we can so they build that feature ;)